# Stop program execution when there is error

Tags: lex

I would like like to stop the execution of the program when facing some error. 
How to do that when using lex? I can just call normal C exit like:

```
exit( status );
```

or is there a more neat way to do it with Lex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just that - but:

- Just printing a message to the standard error and exiting is what lex does—when it encounters a fatal error, e.g., buffer allocation problems.  See for example YY_FATAL_ERROR, which is used for that purpose.  It can be overridden, e.g., to an error *recovery* routine.
- A typical lexer does not exit with an error: it returns state information to the parser which decides whether a state is legal.

If your lexer serves as the parser, then exiting from the lexer would make sense.

Further reading:

- [Does YY_FATAL_ERROR require a call to exit?](http://sourceforge.net/p/flex/mailman/message/29126320/)
- [Re: Ungraceful handling of fatal flex errors](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21862.980612139@sss.pgh.pa.us)
- [flex yy_fatal_error exist just like that. I want handler back to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341967/flex-yy-fatal-error-exist-just-like-that-i-want-handler-back-to-application)